# Array to string conversion notice when using implode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have multiple strings I got from a json array which I put into another array like so:

```
$myArray = $anotherArray = new array();

if($stringA != ""){
     $myArray[] = $stringA;
}elseif($stringB != ""){
     $myArray[] = $stringB;
} //so on...
```

I want to put all of this in the database in a single column so I push the strings into 1 array. Then, I convert the array using implode:

```
if(is_array($myArray)){
    $newString = implode(" ", $myArray);
}
```

This worked fine in my localhost but when we moved the file to a server and run it via cron, I received the notice Array to string conversion.

I've used similar code on the same file for different sets of strings but that one did not get an error so I'm not sure what's going on here.

I've also tried using array_values in the implode function like so:

```
$newString = implode(" ", array_values($myArray));
```

But that didn't work either. I'm not sure if this means anything either but there are some instances wherein aside from the regular text, I get the word Array printed as well. So my question is, what's the possible cause of this error and how can I address it?

Comment: tell php that `$myArray[]` is array....write `$myArray = array();` before if statement.

Comment: I've already included it. Although I'm not sure if this makes a difference. I have another array so my declaration's like this: $myArray = $anotherArray = array();

Comment: `$myArray = $anotherArray` this meaning you are setting `$myArray` value equal to `$anotherArray`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just json_encode your array?

```
$newString  = json_encode($myArray);
```

And also the notice is probably because one of your strings are probably an array and you probably do not see this on your localhost because you must not have error reporting turned on in your php.

Try adding this to your cron job script.

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been trying to figure it out for hours. I've opened the original json array and found that one of strings I was trying to pass to the array is also an array and so, I got the error. Thanks a lot.